# How do I find the openpyxl version number

Tags: python, anaconda, openpyxl

I was given a PC with anaconda already installed.  I have got no idea which version it is other than 3.

Whenever I try to lookup techniques on openpyxl, there seem to be several, depending on the version of openpyxl.  One answer will say do it one way for version 1.8, another will say do it some other way for 2.5.

How do I find out which version of openpyxl is installed so I can avoid trying techniques that either no longer work or only work for later versions.

I've looked through https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.html .  There doesn't seem to be a function that returns the version number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you have imported `openpyxl`, `openpyxl.__version__` gives the version number.

Comment: Took a while to get it going - had to use `__version__` instead of `openpyxl.__version__`

Comment: @cup, that's probably because you use something like `from openpyxl import __version__` rather than `import openpyxl`.

Comment: @paxdiablo - you're right - I had a *from openpyxl import \**

Answer (score 5):

You can also find the version from an installer package if you used one. I installed openpyxl using pip3, so `pip3 list` at the shell prompt will show the current version for all pip3 installed packages. You may need to use `pip list` if that is what was used on your machine.

```
Package                Version   
---------------------- ----------
astroid                2.3.3     
certifi                2019.11.28
chardet                3.0.4     
click                  7.1.1     
dnspython              1.16.0    
et-xmlfile             1.0.1     
idna                   2.9       
isort                  4.3.21    
jdcal                  1.4.1     
lazy-object-proxy      1.4.3     
lml                    0.0.9     
mccabe                 0.6.1     
mysql-connector-python 8.0.19    
openpyxl               3.0.3
```

Comment: On some systems like Anaconda3, you have to use *pip list* since pip3 is called pip.

Comment: @cup - good point. I edited my comment to note that the pip version may vary. Thanks.